# How can I troubleshoot MySQL access denied error for user 'root'@'localhost'?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

```
Error executing query: Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at PromisePool.execute (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:374:22)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\routes\dashboard\members\admin.js:153:39
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PFE\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3) {
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: '28000',
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

I don't have solution for this problem for mysql. I use express.js and ejs in my code

Comment: You should never use the user `root` to connect to your database. Consider creating and connecting with a new user with the proper permissions

Comment: Have you checked the password? Have you tried to use the same user and password with the command line client?